# Why is my code failing to compile? (perfect forwarding and parameter packs)

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, variadic-functions

Here is the program:

```
#include <memory>

struct A;

struct B {
    void fn(A* ptr) {}
};

template<typename ...Args>
void foo(B* b, void (B::*func)(Args...), Args&&... args)
{
    (b->*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

struct A {
    void bar() { B b; foo(&b, &B::fn, this); } // fails
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    foo(&b, &B::fn, &a); // passes
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the compiler output:

```
foo.cpp: In member function 'void A::bar()':
foo.cpp:16:47: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(B*, void (B::*)(A*), A* const)'
     void bar() { B b; foo(&b, &B::fn, this); } // fails
                                           ^
foo.cpp:16:47: note: candidate is:
foo.cpp:10:10: note: template<class ... Args> void foo(B*, void (B::*)(Args ...), Args&& ...)
     void foo(B* b, void (B::*func)(Args...), Args&&... args)
          ^
foo.cpp:10:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
foo.cpp:16:47: note:   inconsistent parameter pack deduction with 'A*' and 'A* const'
         void bar() { B b; foo(&b, &B::fn, this); } // fails
```

I cannot figure out why one call works and one call fails.

**EDIT :** Changing the parameter pack to `Args...` from `Args&&...` solves the compiler problem.  But, I would still like to know why it fails.

Comment: Which compiler and which version?

Comment: g++ 4.8.2 with --std=c++11   (also fails on VS2013 with C2782)

Comment: @T.C. It happens on VC++14, so no, it's not caused by the problem you have identified.

Comment: @cybermonkey It works on GCC 4.9+ and Clang. Considering how broken MSVC often is with templates, I don't take its behavior as evidence of anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a template parameter (or parameter pack) is used in two deduced contexts, deduction is done independently for each and the result must match. This makes things like

```
template<typename ...Args>
void foo(B* b, void (B::*func)(Args...), Args&&... args) { /* ... */ }
```

tricky to use at best, because `Args` is being deduced from both the member function signature and the subsequent pack of arguments; coupled with the special rules for forwarding references, you'll usually not be getting an exact match.

Now, in this case, you *should* get an exact match, because `this` is a prvalue of type `A*`, so `Args` will be deduced as the non-reference type `A*` according to the forwarding reference rules, and that happens to match the signature of `B::fn`. Unfortunately, due to [bug 56701](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56701), GCC 4.8 considers `this` to have type `A* const` and deduces `Args` accordingly (and MSVC apparently has the same bug), causing a mismatch.

I recommend making `func`'s type a template parameter, side-stepping the double-deduction issue entirely.

```
template<typename PMF, typename ...Args>
void foo(B* b, PMF func, Args&&... args) { /* ... */ }
```

Alternatively, you can constrain `func` to "pointer to member of `B` of some sort":

```
template<typename F, typename ...Args>
void foo(B* b, F B::* func, Args&&... args) { /* ... */ }
```

Both also have the benefit of handling pointer to `const` member functions properly, compared to the original.

If you really want to constrain `func`'s type further, use two packs:

```
template<typename ...Args, typename... FArgs>
void foo(B* b, void (B::*func)(FArgs...), Args&&... args)
```

Another possible workaround, for this case only, involves playing with `this` to try to remove the erroneous const-qualification; `+this` works with GCC 4.8 but not MSVC; `&*this` works with MSVC but not GCC 4.8; `+&*this` seems to work with both but is getting into line-noise territory...

Comment: What does the + on a pointer do?  I can't find any references explaining the + on a pointer.

Comment: @cup It returns the value of the pointer unchanged; usually used to force a function/array-to-pointer decay. The idea here is that it returns a fresh value copy, which shouldn't have the const-qualification.